# Using a service to start an ongoing notification that can take an action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I've created a service so that I can have a persistent notification. I want this notification to have an option that will send an intent to another of my activities.

The option will inherently be stopped every process that the app has spawned. So the notification also needs to close once the action is pressed.

I'm trying to accomplish this using a pending broadcast intent, but for some reason the broadcast receiver isn't catching the intent. I register the receiver dynamically in the service's onCreate() method and unregister it in the service's onDestroy() method.

```
public class myService extends IntentService {
    private boolean shown = false;
    private ButtonReceiver buttonReceiver;

    //Side note: this is legacy code. Necessary?
    public myService() {
        super("myService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.myapp.KILL_NOTIFICATION");
        this.buttonReceiver = new ButtonReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(this.buttonReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(this.buttonReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction() == "com.myapp.START_SERVICE") {
            //generate a unique id for the notification
            int id = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()));

            //create a pending intent to send off when the kill action is pressed
            Intent buttonIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.KILL_NOTIFICATION");
            buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", id);
            PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, buttonIntent, 0);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setAutoCancel(false);
            builder.setContentTitle("my app");
            //builder.setContentText("Press this notification to kill.");
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            //builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp, "Kill my app", btPendingIntent);
            builder.setWhen(0);
            builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            //TODO need to find first unused notif id
            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        }
    }

    public class ButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);

            Intent killIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.KILL_EVERYTHING");
            killIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            startActivity(killIntent);

            //cancel notification
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IntentService` stops itself after the `onHandleIntent()` method finishes, so your dynamically registered Receiver is no longer around to get the broadcast when it happens.

You don't need a `Service` to maintain an ongoing `Notification`. In your case, you can simply issue the `Notification` directly, instead of starting the `Service` to do it. Then register your Receiver class statically in the manifest, and use an explicit `Intent` to broadcast to it from the `Notification`.

Move `ButtonReceiver` to it's own class file, and register it in the manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name=".ButtonReceiver" />
```

You'll need to call `startActivity()` on the `context` parameter passed into `onReceive()`, like you are `getSystemService()`. You'll also need to add the following flag to the `Intent`.

```
killIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Then just change `buttonIntent` for the `Notification`'s `PendingIntent` to:

```
Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(this, ButtonReceiver.class);
```

If that's the only broadcast `ButtonReceiver` will handle, you won't really need the `KILL_NOTIFICATION` action anymore.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use a service is because my "main" activity isn't persistent. It really just exists as control flow for several other modules and apps, using intents to make decisions. Once that control flow is done (much less than one second) the app finishes so that it doesn't remain in the background. The ongoing notification will need to send an intent to this main activity so that it knows to shut everything down. Will the notification still persist if launched by the main activity?

Comment: Yep. Think about it like this: you're currently issuing the `Notification` from a component that is not persistent - since the `IntentService` finishes right after `onHandleIntent()` is done - and the `Notification` still sticks around, yeah? I myself use a personal app that issues an ongoing `Notification` from a boot Receiver, without ever having even started an a `Activity` or `Service`. An ongoing `Notification` isn't really going anywhere until your app programmatically removes it, or your app is somehow forcibly stopped.

Comment: Awesome. That all sounds correct. I'll accept your answer as soon as I have a chance to implement and test it. Thanks for your help!